# liferay country list is undefined in user account

Tags: json, liferay

When a user clicks on `My Account` and chooses the option `IDENTIFICATION -> Addresses`, the `County` and `Region` drop downs are **Undefined**. In the console yields this ERROR:

```
ERROR:[http-bio-8080-exexc-5][JSONWebServiceServiceAction:97]NO JSON web service action with path /country/getcountries and method null for 
ERROR:[http-bio-8080-exexc-5][JSONWebServiceServiceAction:97]NO JSON web service action with path /region/getregion and method null for
```

Comment: Could you please add your Liferay version?

Comment: additionally, have you done any customization to liferay using hook or ext?